# Couldn't establish Raspberry Pi SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, headless

I am consistently trying to connect to my RPi through SSH but the connection is refusing.

What I did is,
I connect my RPi to my WiFi Router,
Open Router's control panel and look into the DHCP table,
[image]

I then opened puTTy and put this IP address as a Host name,

[image]

but consistently getting this error,

[image]

Anybody knows why I am getting this error :/
I have worked on the RPi through this process before (like a month ago)
but it is not working now.

It merits mentioning that I installed, 
2013-07-26-wheezy-raspbian image file on my RPi

Comment: Have you enabled SSH on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I am using Wheezy Raspbian, SSH is enabled by default.

Comment: Have you port scanned your pi remotely, and does ssh work locally on the pi?

Comment: Ok I got it fixed :)
Actually, the problem was with the McAfee Antivirus, it was blocking the port 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Windows Firewall, since Mcafee preventing the Firewall to establish the connection over port 22. I had to manually allow port 22 using this tutorial,
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall

Comment: I just followed the instructions, couldn't connect. I created a "new Inbound rule" in advanced security. Can you list the instructions to create a Inbound rule? @Sufiyan Ghori